# Replaced tag in aspx form after upload file picture in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, hyperlink, upload

I have in the form aspx this field for upload file picture:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Once the file picture is uploaded in the server, the table of db is updated with the path of file picture.

Now I need to see in the same form the picture already uploaded and replaced the tag FileUpload with tag Hyperlink.

Anybody know how can I resolve do this?

Can you suggest?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit #1**

Okay, this is my new code behind:

```
ImageOnDB = dr["ImageOn"].ToString();
if (ImageOnDB.ToString() != "")
{
    ImageOn.Visible = true;
    FileUpload1.Visible = false;
    ImageButton7.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    ImageOn.Visible = false;
    FileUpload1.Visible = true;
    ImageButton7.Visible = true;
}
```

And this code in aspx page:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ImageOn" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ImageOnDB").ToString() %>'
    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageOnDB").ToString() %>'
    ToolTip="ImageOnDB"
    Target="_blank" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Transparent">
</asp:HyperLink>

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

But the **Hyperlink** ImageOn is empty, I don't have error ... in DB the value of column **ImageOn** is

```
http://myserver/myaspnet/public/TEST.JPG
```

Comment: You add an `<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Visible="False" ID="hyperlink1">` to the page as well. After a file has been seved, you set `FileUpload1.Visible = false` and at the same time set the `hyperlink1.NavigateUrl` and change `hyperlink1.Visible`to `true`

Comment: @RobertFricke Thank you, please see **Edit #1** in my first question...

Answer (score 0):

In your .cs file:

```
ImageOnDB = dr["ImageOn"].ToString();
if (ImageOnDB.ToString() != "")
{
    ImageOn.Visible = true;
    ImageOn.ImageUrl = dr["ImageOn"].ToString();
    ImageOn.NavigateUrl = dr["ImageOn"].ToString();
    ImageOn.ToolTip = dr["ImageOn"].ToString();
    ImageOn.Target = "_blank";
    FileUpload1.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    ImageOn.Visible = false;
    FileUpload1.Visible = true;
}
```